# Magento - Custom subject of order email

Tags: php, email, magento

I have a service in PHP which interacts with a Magento website. I can't access the source code of this website. So I can use service to order a product and send a mail. When I call

```
$order->sendNewOrderEmail();
```

an email will be send to my email-id with subject `Nuovo ordine # XXXXXXXXX`.

Now I want add a string to this subject: `TEST - Nuovo ordine # XXXXXXXXX`.

How I can do it?

Comment: Have you used template from tansaction emails for your email ?

Comment: No I don't call any templates in code, I only make an order and call $order->sendNewOrderEmail(); to send email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` find `sendNewOrderEmail()` method. Then find

```
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
        )
    );
```

Here is array of variables from template. Add one new param for test:

```
            'test'         => $is_test ? $is_test : ''
```

Change `$is_test` to your condition. For example:

```
public function sendNewOrderEmail($is_test = FALSE)
```

Now open your template file `app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new_guest.html` (for example).

Find subject variable on the first line: `<!--@subject Nuovo ordine # {{var order.increment_id}} @-->` or something like this.

Make changes:
`<!--@subject {{var is_test}}Nuovo ordine # {{var order.increment_id}} @-->`

Call method:

```
$order->sendNewOrderEmail('TEST - ');
```