# How to change Order Email Subject in Order.php Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to change order email subject in Magento for the `order.php` file.

Here is my code:

```
$mailSubject = "This is test subject";
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->setTemplateSubject($mailSubject);
$translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
```

It's not working. Is there any other way to set subject in order.php

I don't want to set from Transaction Emails option from back-end as there is a value generated by PHP I want to send in the subject line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` find `sendNewOrderEmail()` method. Then find

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
        'order'        => $this,
        'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
        'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
    )
);
```

=> Here is array of variables from template. Add one new param for test:

'test'         => $is_test ? $is_test : ''

=> Change $is_test to your condition. For example:

public function sendNewOrderEmail($is_test = FALSE)

Now open your template file `app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new_guest.html` (for example).

Find subject variable on the first line:  or something like this.

Make changes:

=> Call method:
$order->sendNewOrderEmail('TEST - ');

Answer (score 0):

goto>/app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales select template and change subject directly

Answer (score 0):

Just refer the following URL for correct answer.

[Magento - Custom subject of order email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076729/magento-custom-subject-of-order-email)

And try to change customizations through custom magento module.Suppose you are going to **update magento** means it may **cause some issues**.

Create a **new custom module** and do the customizations in proper way.